# Any returns false when in real DB - I do have records

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

Here is the code

```
DContext.Views
        .Include("Torrent")
        .Include("Viewer")
        .Any(V => V.Torrent.ID == DTorrent.ID &&
                  V.UserHostAddress == UserHostAddress &&
                  V.Viewer.ID == ViewerTIKSNID.Value)
```

It returns FALSE but in database I have couple of rows having exactly same information.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this.

Comment: Are you confident DTorrent.ID, UserHostAddress and ViewerTIKSNID.Value all contain the values you think they do?  Additionally are you sure the include path you've specified contains any entities at all?  This behaviour could result from a number of different problems.  What's the result of calling .ToList() after your .Include("Viewer")?  Simple debugging should give you the answer you need!

Comment: I am sure that in database I have more then one row matching to given values, I debugged and checked it's values. Thank you from .ToList() and .Include("Viewer") ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should write **V.Viewer.TIKSNID** instead of **V.Viewer.ID**. Very simple and stupid bug ha?